# gzip specific files

Tags: gzip

for some reason these files are not gzipping on my apache server, chrome network tab shows this. Is there a specific directive I can add to htaccess to cache these files?

```
Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by about two thirds (~680.45KB):
adae8bc4c3cb52cbe22358aaced87a72.css could save ~607B
css_f91fa8d73b5e7661d6dcf9e58395e533.css could save ~59.54KB
jquery.min.js could save ~37.27KB
drupal.js could save ~6.15KB
auto_image_handling.js could save ~6.72KB
lightbox.js could save ~29.38KB
superfish.js could save ~2.42KB
jquery.bgiframe.min.js could save ~1011B
jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js could save ~1.05KB
nice_menus.js could save ~581B
panels.js could save ~531B
jquery.pngFix.js could save ~2.98KB
jquery.cycle.all.min.js could save ~20.20KB
views_slideshow.js could save ~8.76KB
views_slideshow.js could save ~9.02KB
wanderlust_custom_videos.js could save ~598B
wl_helper.js could save ~777B
extlink.js could save ~2.88KB
cufon-yui.js could save ~11.89KB
googleanalytics.js could save ~1.48KB
swfobject.js could save ~6.65KB
jquery.jcarousel.min.js could save ~10.19KB
jcarousel.js could save ~6.01KB
Akzidenz_Grotesk_BE_Super_800.font.js could save ~14.27KB
Akzidenz_Grotesk_BE_Bold_700.font.js could save ~12.96KB
Akzidenz_Grotesk_BE_Cn_400.font.js could save ~13.39KB
SuperCondensed_500.font.js could save ~24.40KB
FuturaBold_700.font.js could save ~26.19KB
Futura_500.font.js could save ~57.70KB
SuperGroteskB_500.font.js could save ~23.86KB
jquery.cookie.js could save ~1.25KB
wanderlust.js could save ~1.69KB
sliderbottom.js could save ~442B
jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js could save ~4.60KB
jcarousellite_control.js could save ~224B
sitesdropdown.js could save ~1.09KB
widgets.js could save ~50.13KB
cufon-drupal.js could save ~599B
swfobject_api.js could save ~348B
ga.js could save ~24.02KB
all.js could save ~124.67KB
tweet_button.1347008535.html could save ~38.43KB
xd_arbiter.php could save ~16.80KB
xd_arbiter.php could save ~16.80KB
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at mod_deflate: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you are concerned about gzip I assume your main concern is performance. Ideally, `.htaccess` directives should be enabled in an `httpd.conf` but if you are like me and working with shared hosting then you are relegated to `.htaccess`.

I asked a [potentially related question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/447705/enabling-gzip-with-htaccess-why-is-it-hit-or-miss).

If `mod_deflate` is available to be enabled, the code in that question (and for that matter the repo I link to in a comment) will enable it on for `JS` and `CSS`.

That said, that is a ridiculous number of separate `JS` files and if it is at all possible you should combine them into as few files as possible.