# Enable gzip for source maps

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate, mime-type

I'm using the Grunt plugins to concat, minify and generate source maps of my Javascript before I push it to the production server (I'll soon be doing the same with `SASS` for `CSS`).

The source maps generated are plain text but with an file 'extension' of `.map` (e.g. `plugins.js.map`). Apparently, they aren't being gzipped.

I'm on shared hosting so limited to `.htaccess` and I assume this is as simple as adding `.map` to what seems to be a list of `MIME-types` in my existing `.htaccess`.

For reference, I'm using the [code in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/447705/enabling-gzip-with-htaccess-why-is-it-hit-or-miss) (which is taken verbatim from the HTML5 Bolierplate repo).

Everything else is being served with gzip, the source maps are the only things which are not.

What do I need to do to ensure that my source maps are also served with compression?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag, but I tried to create `source-maps` as a tag to make it easier for others to find this question. I know source maps are fairly new and front-end related but I suspect others will have the same question. If appropriate, could someone with adequate reputation add that tag?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why bother? They're not going to get downloaded by anyone who isn't using the inspectors.

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was the case. Both PageSpeed and YSlow browser extensions were giving me messages about it improving performance, it made me wonder if it loaded for all users.